# google reflections not resolving my type parameters on annotated methods

Tags: java, annotations, urlclassloader, reflections

I have the following code that works nicely if the project is in my classpath locally and I do a getClass().getClassLoader().  But when I try to load dynamically from an external jar it fails.

It fails to load MyType, which is the type on the method parameter like this:

```
@MyAnnotation("FOO.BAR")
public Object echo(@Valid MyType param) throws Exception {
    return...;
}
```

This code will fail with "org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name MyType":

```
myLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///"+jarfile)}); 
myLoaders.Add(myLoader);
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .addClassLoaders(loaders)
    .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(myPackage, myLoaders));
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(builder);
return  reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

I believe the problem lies in the class loader.  Is there another way to load a jar such that it picks up all the types?

Comment: How are you loading / starting this program?  Where is the Jar file with `MyType` in it?

Comment: The executable is run with java -jar.  It then loads an external jar for reflection as seen in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solved it by using forClassLoader instead of forPackage.

Comment: I don't know if something changed or if I got the worst false positive ever, but it is not working now even with the forClassLoader.  At this point I'm stumped and thinking this is a limitation of google's reflection library.

Comment: Scratch that.  I am convinced they changed the 0.9.9-RC on maven central and broke me.  I just updated to 0.9.10 and it is working again!